# Should I merge dev and master branches before the development is completely done?

Tags: git, github, merge

So, I have `master` and `development` branch on a GitHub repo.
Branch `master` has only the initial commit, and all the development we've done is on the `development` branch.
Recently, we've finished the core of the project, and users are using it now; soon we will start to work further on some additional requirements.
I am new to git and I was wondering what is a good practice now?
Should I merge `master` into `development` now (and do it every time we finish a big part of the project, that is for example made available to users), or should we develop on the `development` branch until we are completely done with the project?
My main concern is that I could jeopardize the project and end up in some merge conflicts that will take time to resolve if I am merging the `master` and `development` branches too often (as I see many people end up in problems).
What is the best practice on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the development you have done is on one branch, why not make that master? Adding a branch just gives you an overhead if you're only using one.

In general it's good to merge master often so that the number of changes is smaller, lowering the risk of merge conflicts.

Alternatively you could use short lived feature branches, where you work on branches when developing new smaller features and regularly merge them into master.

If you want to be sure you can try merging locally and if you don't want to get rid of your attempt reset to what your remote has with

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for such a fast answer! So, ideally, I shouldn't expect any conflicts from merging dev and master, if I'm not changing master branch? I am new to git and I like to check out possible consequences before I do smt.. and I noticed that this merging can be a pain..

Comment: Conflicts occur when two different branches have changes to the same files. If the files don't exist in one of the branches (in this case master as there is nothing on master) then you shouldn't expect conflicts. You can also try this locally and if it doesn't work out reset to what is on your remote `git push origin HEAD --force` but this will lose any local changes too.

Comment: Thanks for further clarification. I just merged master into development, without any problems. I will keep doing this whenever a bigger part of development is finished.